# Parallax.js inside Fullpage.js creating unexpected result on Mac Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax, fullpage.js

I am using [parallax js](https://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/) inside my fullpage.js slides. Its working fine everywhere except Mac Safari, here its overlapping the image while sliding to next slide and when the animation ended it comes back to its position.

Check the snippet below you can only get the bug on Mac Safari.

Can we fix this bug somehow ?

```js
// variables
var $header_top = $('.header-top');
var $nav = $('nav');



// toggle menu 
$header_top.find('a').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('open-menu');
});



// fullpage customization
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  sectionsColor: ['#B8AE9C', '#348899', '#F2AE72', '#5C832F', '#B8B89F'],
  sectionSelector: '.vertical-scrolling',
  slideSelector: '.horizontal-scrolling',
  navigation: true,
  slidesNavigation: true,
  controlArrows: false,
  anchors: ['firstSection', 'secondSection', 'thirdSection', 'fourthSection', 'fifthSection'],
  menu: '#menu',

  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
    $header_top.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .3)');
    $nav.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .25)');
    if (index == 5) {
      $('#fp-nav').hide();
    }
  },

  onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
    if (index == 5) {
      $('#fp-nav').show();
    }
  },

  afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
    if (anchorLink == 'fifthSection' && slideIndex == 1) {
      $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'up');
      $header_top.css('background', 'transparent');
      $nav.css('background', 'transparent');
      $(this).css('background', '#374140');
      $(this).find('h2').css('color', 'white');
      $(this).find('h3').css('color', 'white');
      $(this).find('p').css({
        'color': '#DC3522',
        'opacity': 1,
        'transform': 'translateY(0)'
      });
    }
  },

  onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction) {
    if (anchorLink == 'fifthSection' && slideIndex == 1) {
      $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true, 'up');
      $header_top.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .3)');
      $nav.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .25)');
    }
  }
});


var scenes = [];
var scenesSelector = document.querySelectorAll('.scene');
for (i = 0; i < scenesSelector.length; i++) {
  scenes[i] = new Parallax(scenesSelector[i]);
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:300,400,700);

/* ICON STYLES - ICON FROM: http://fontastic.me/
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

@font-face {
  font-family: "untitled-font-1";
  src: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/untitled-font-1.eot");
  src: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/untitled-font-1.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/untitled-font-1.woff") format("woff"), url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/untitled-font-1.ttf") format("truetype"), url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/untitled-font-1.svg#untitled-font-1") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"]:after,
[class*=" icon-"]:after {
  font-family: "untitled-font-1";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.fp-tableCell{
  position: relative;
}
.icon-up-open-big {
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon-up-open-big:after {
  content: "a";
  font-size: 2.5em;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: color .3s;
  transition: color .3s;
}

.icon-up-open-big:hover:after {
  color: white;
}

.scroll-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}


/* HELPER CLASSES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.l-left {
  float: left;
}

.l-right {
  float: right;
}

.end {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(300px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(300px);
  transform: translateY(300px);
  -webkit-transition: opacity, -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: opacity, transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}


/* RESET-GENERAL STYLES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: .18em;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* NAV STYLES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

.header-top {
  background: rgba(0, 47, 77, .3);
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 12;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}

h1 a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.toggle-menu {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}

.toggle-menu i {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  width: 30px;
  left: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.toggle-menu i:nth-child(1) {
  top: 16px;
}

.toggle-menu i:nth-child(2) {
  top: 24px;
}

.toggle-menu i:nth-child(3) {
  top: 32px;
}

.open-menu i:nth-child(1) {
  top: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}

.open-menu i:nth-child(2) {
  background: transparent;
}

.open-menu i:nth-child(3) {
  top: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
}

nav {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(0, 47, 77, .25);
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s;
  transition: all 3s;
}

.open-menu~nav {
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 80px 0;
  z-index: 15;
  height: calc(90vh - 70px);
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

nav li {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

nav li a {
  font-size: 2em;
  display: block;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: background .3s;
  transition: background .3s;
}

nav li:nth-child(odd) a,
body.fp-viewing-fifthSection-1 #menu li:nth-child(5) a {
  background: #962D3E;
}

nav li:nth-child(even) a {
  background: #aa3346;
}

nav li:nth-child(odd) a:hover {
  background: #9e2f41;
}

nav li:nth-child(even) a:hover {
  background: #c53c52;
}

nav li.active a,
body.fp-viewing-fifthSection-1 #menu li:last-child a {
  background: #453659;
}

.col {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.img img {
  width: 100%;
}


/* SECTION STYLES - fullPage.js 
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

section {
  text-align: center;
  /*background: url('https://unsplash.it/1910/1221?image=626') no-repeat center / cover;*/
}

h2 {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-size: 4em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2.8em;
}


/* SLIDENAV STYLES - fullPage.js 
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#fp-nav ul li a span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a span {
  background: white;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin: -4px 0 0 -4px;
}

#fp-nav ul li a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a.active span,
#fp-nav ul li:hover a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li:hover a.active span {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: -8px 0 0 -8px;
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #24221F;
}


/* MQ STYLES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  nav ul {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  nav li {
    margin-top: 1px;
  }
  nav li a {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  .scroll-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  html {
    font-size: 50%;
  }
  .open-menu~nav {
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
  nav li a {
    padding: 3px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.7/fullpage.extensions.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax/3.1.0/parallax.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class="header-top clearfix">
    <h1 class="l-left"><a href="#firstSection">Your Logo</a></h1>
    <a class="l-right toggle-menu" href="#">
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>

<div id="fullpage">
  <section class="vertical-scrolling">
    <h2>fullPage.js</h2>
    <h3>This is the first section</h3>
    <div class="scroll-icon">
      <p>Jump into the last slide</p>
      <a href="#fifthSection/1" class="icon-up-open-big"></a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="vertical-scrolling shadow">
    <h2>fullPage.js</h2>
    <h3>This is the second section</h3>
    <p class="img scene"><img data-depth="0.8" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></p>
    <div class="col">
      <h2>Column</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="vertical-scrolling">
    <h2>fullPage.js</h2>
    <h3>This is the third section</h3>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the parallax library you want to use relies on the scroll event or position, then you'll need to make use of the fullPage.js option `scrollBar:true`.